# Reflection/Introspection of JavaScript Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Assume I have:

```
// test.js
function myFunc(a,b,c) {
    return "Test";
}
module.exports.myFunc = myFunc;
```

How can I **dynamically** find out that test.js has a function myFunc which takes 3 parameters, so:

```
x = require('test.js')
if ( x has function defined myFunc ) {
  if ( function myFunc in x has 3 arguments) {
     "OK"
  } else { "Expect 3 params"}
} else { 
  "test.js does not expose myFunc" }
```

Is this possible using reflection/introspection?

Thanks

Comment: [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect).

Comment: For the first part of your question (does x have a function called myFunc), you could use this: `'myFunc' in x && typeof x.myFunc === 'function'`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specific to modules. Function arity can be determined with `length` property in JavaScript, `myFunc.length === 3`.

Relying on `length` in production is contradictory practice that often designates code smell. In tests, expected `length` behaviour may be undesirable.

Not too good:

```
function myFunc(...args) {
   const [a,b,c] = args;
}

myFunc.length === 0;
```

Not good at all:

```
function myFunc(a, b = 1, c = 2) {}

myFunc.length === 1;
```

If `myFunc.length` is expected to be used in unit tests, it's recommended to skip this assertion and focus on function behaviour instead.